# iphone :find the error in this code

Tags: iphone

Hi I want to know what is the problem with the following code

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button release];
```

Comment: What is your problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code gives you a `autoreleased` object.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

If you call release on it, it'll crash.

Answer (score 0):

Error with you code is :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

In this line you are not allocating the object of `UIButton`. Which means you don't have control on when to release it. This line is correct.

```
[button release];
```

On this line you are trying to release the `button`. Control to release this object isn't with you as you have not allocated it. If you want to use release. Then alloc your `UIButton` object first.